# Delete Project Type from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How do I delete a Project Type from Visual Studio?  I've created one and installed it with a VSIX file, but I want to alter it, and the new VSIX file says I can't install the new one because the old one exists.

TIA.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and what do you mean by type? Do you mean template?

Comment: I've in 2013.  By type, I mean when you say File, New, Project, it lists Win32 Console Application, MFC Application, Win32 Project, Empty Project, Makefile Project, and other project types that I created.  I want to erase the ones I created.  Tx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to remove these by going to

> \My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates

Then search for the `ZIP` file that contains the project type you want to delete. Delete that file should remove it for you.

For the others you can't find check out Tools => Extensions and Updates. Search for the types there and choose "Uninstall"

Comment: I have four things to delete.  That eliminated one of them. I also searched ...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\My Exported Templates.  Any idea where else to look?

Comment: Try searching the entire My Documtens folder for one of the names as well as \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12 (the number might be different for 2010 but you will see the folder I am talking about)

Comment: I have some copies on my C: drive, records of where I was working, but I changed the paths.  Nothing in \Program Files (x86).  Hm.

Comment: Have you gone into Visual Studio then tool then Extensions nd Updates and see if your stuff is in there. It might show up since you used a VSIX file, if it does just uninstall it.

Comment: Hey, it works! ...For the benefit of others, I ask you to update your answer to include your last comment (and anything else you find appropriate), and I will accept it as the answer.  My computer thanks you!

Comment: @WillBriggs Answer updated. Glad that got it for you.